# Как дать пользователю возможность самому настраивать стили?

Tags: java, css, javafx, gui, fxml

Я делаю чат и хочу сделать его красивым, но у меня с этим проблемы, поэтому я хочу дать пользователям менять css-файл в случае надобности. У меня есть GUI, сделанный через SceneBuilder, но суть в том, что css-файл используется только через исходники, я хочу чтобы файл со стилями лежал рядом с jar-архивом программы. Чтобы если пользователь изменил что-то в этом файле, то это отразилось на интерфейсе после открытия программы. Я просто не понимаю как это сделать, но мне это нужно, несмотря на то, что проект open-source и его итак может изменить кто хочет.

Comment: Храните настройки стилей в папке пользователя в ОС. Применяйте данные стили в коде: Считывайте файл и добавляйте стили.

Comment: Мне как раз и надо только то, как считывать стили с файла, так то я знаю где я хочу его хранить и что с ним делать.

Comment: @Tsyklop как считывать-то? И куда писать?

Comment: Нужно сначала определиться с форматом этого файла. Я склоняюсь к `json`-у. Где ключ это название класса, а значение это объект, в котором ключ это название css свойства, а значение - значение этого свойства.

Comment: @Tsyklop зачем такие сложности? Я хочу иметь просто CSS-файл, лежащий в одной папке с программой. При загрузке программа читала оттуда стиль и закидывала его в JavaFX